# Enabling access logs for Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

What is the way to enable access logs after the load balancer is configured. And what is the max duration we can set for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable Access logs on Application Load Balancer:

1. Select the Load Balancer on which Access logs needs to be enabled.
2. Under the Description, select Edit Attributes.
3. Enable Access Logs.
4. Select S3 bucket to store the logs.
5. Make sure the S3 bucket has to write permission to write the logs.
6. Verify that the Access logs for Application Load Balancer stored in the S3 Bucket.

If we set Lifecycle policy on S3 bucket to delete objects after a particular time period, then logs will get deleted. Otherwise, access logs persist until we delete logs or S3 bucket manually.